# How to use a bank in Neverwinter without being in a guild?

Tags: neverwinter

I read that it is possible to deposit up to 16 items in bank, but when I approach the bank in **Protector's Enclave** it denies me access for "not being in a guild"

Is it possible to use the bank to store items without being in a guild, and if yes, how?

Comment: Guild bank is a distinct entity. Regular bank is for (separately) account-wide and character storage.

Comment: Seems like such a simple thing, but good question here. Ran into this myself when I started this past weekend. Spent half my time wondering why they didn't have regular player banks, before I noticed the other tellers. Easy to miss since most other NPCs stand outside, so you don't expect to see them where they are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use the bank without being in a guild. When you approach the bank, the NPC in the center is the Guild Banker, used to access guild-only storage; to his left and right (in yellow below) are two other NPCs you can approach, who are the regular bankers, used to access your personal storage.

[image]